# How to send data from my class to my method in DART?

Tags: flutter, class, dart, methods

i need to send some data from my class to a method in Dart.

Here is an example of my code:

```
class ScreenState extends State<Screen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF0578be),
        title: Text("${widget.nome}"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
        children: <Widget>[
          _method(
            idTxt = widget.txt,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

_method() {
/// my logic
}
```

How could i do that? It's possible?

I need receive the value idTxt = widget.text on the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the data when you are calling a method Like this  `_myMethod(data)` and In method,receive the data `_myMethod(String data){print(data);}`  here String is for String type Data.

but I have to say, your code are foggy to me, that's why I am not using your code in the example!

Comment: yeah, it's just an example. it's not the code i will use on my application. i'll test, i'm not use to work with dart

Comment: @SecchiZ ok, test it, and if there any problem,let me know!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the value in your method simply place inside the brackets.

```
class ScreenState extends State<Screen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF0578be),
        title: Text("${widget.nome}"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
        children: <Widget>[
          _method(
            idTxt = widget.txt,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

_method(idTxt) {
/// my logic
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do like that

```
_method(idTxt) {
  //logic
}
```

and call him

```
_method(
    widget.txt,
),
```